# Rails Rake task errors out while console equivalent does not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, console, rake

I have a piece of code that works fine in the console, but in a cron-driven rake task, it errors out every time, saying that the accessor function for one of the has_many relationships is not a valid method. Example:

provider has_many instances, so I'm calling provider.instances, and the rake task will throw back an error:

```
"undefined method `instances' for "#<Provider:0x7fff1c18a5d8>":Provider"
```

In the console, the same function pasted in works fine.

The rake call:

```
rake RAILS_ENV=production scheduled:update_recurring --trace
```

The console initialization:

```
script/console production
```

Rails version 2.3.2

See anything obvious?

UPDATE:
The rake file is setup as so:

```
namespace :scheduled do
    task :update_recurring => :environment do
        Stuff that worked in console but not rake here
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact same problem. The only way I could get it to work was to reload the class that caused the error.

```
task :my_task => :environment do
  load "#{Rails.root}/app/models/my_class.rb" # Needed to do this

  foo = MyClass.create(my_attr: 'bar') # my_attr will be nil (huh??) unless I load the class
  foo.items.create(...) # This is the has_many that failed before loading the class
end
```

It's like the class loader loaded the class name, but it didn't get any of the definition.

Comment: I realized that in my case, I was reopening class at the beginning of the task (`class Account < ActiveRecord::Base; ...; end`)and then calling `account = Account.find`, so it had no idea that `Account` existing somewhere else. Calling `account = Account.find` first did the job =)

Answer (score 0):

In your console, the rails environment is loaded for you.

I am hoping that you have loaded the rails environment when you created the rails task.

**Update**

"RAILS_ENV=production"

just specifies the that which environment you are using thats all,so you can use it with "ENV["RAILS_ENV"]" inside your code.

to load rails you need to do this.

```
  require File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/../config/environment"
```

Comment: RAILS_ENV=production specifies that rake load the production rails environment, right?

Comment: I think the environment is loading properly, the other ActiveRecord relationships are working.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tell rake that your task is dependent on loading the Rails environment?

```
namespace :scheduled do
 task :update_recurring => :environment do
   ...
 end 
end
```

Comment: Yeah, that's how it's setup verbatim
namespace :scheduled do
task :update_recurring => :environment do
code that worked in console, but not in rake here
end
end